# What do kids call their living great-grandparents?

Tags: word-choice

How do kids address or refer to their great-grandparents, if they are still alive? (equivalent to "dad", "mom", "grandpa", "grandma") "Great-grandpa" sounds rather lame.

Comment: This is going to be culturally-specific, and may even vary from family to family.

Comment: @JohnF is exactly right; there’s no standard name like “Mom” or “Dad” for great-grandparents. I was lucky enough to have three great-grandparents still alive when I was in high school. One great-grandmother was called “Nana” and another was called “Ma” (everyone called her “Ma” – her children, her grandchildren, and her great-grandchildren). Nicknames for grandparents and great-grandparents is something that is very family-specific. This is a good question, though.

Comment: My kids are half German so they have Grandma, Grandad, Opa, Oma.

Comment: I have to concur with the other commenters here that this is culture-specific, with one caveat: English is a language that loves its Ellipsis and thus tends to drop the "great" prefixes when all parties of a conversation have the relevant knowledge to follow along. Example: _My great-great-grandfather Joseph and my great-grandmother Allison are visiting. Grandpa Joseph let me borrow his car to take myself and Grandma Allison to the mall._ This will also happen in conversation; unless they have a specific epithet (like 'Nana' for Grandma Allison), which will get used instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here in Pakistan, there are specific words that kids use to call the great grand parents.

However, as of what I know, there's no *specific* word in English which can be used for great grandparents.

**It varies according to the culture and to the family.** In some families, you would notice kids calling both their great grandparents and grandparents by one single name, that is "Grandpa" and "Grandma". In some, I have seen kids using specific words for their great grandparents like "Grandma Norma", any cute and simple word is used..

Answer (score 1):

It is a rare situation. It is unusual for a child to have a close relationship with a great-grandparent.  The answer will vary from family to family.

I knew one of my great-grandparents.  I called him "Pop"<sup>*</sup> It was his nickname in the family. In other families a great grandmother might be called "Nana" or "Ma" and so on.

For a learner, this is even less of a problem.  You refer to your great grandparent in their language, not English.  And when talking *about* your family you refer to them as "great grandfather" or "great granddad" or "great grandpa" (depending on your relationships)

---

* <sub>If I called him anything at all, which was rare, for an 8-year-old, a 90-year-old man is unimaginably ancient, wrinkly and really rather scary.  He was certainly too old to "play" with, and 8-year-olds don't really enjoy sitting beside a bed and chatting.</sub>